# Using Pentaho Community Edition with SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, pentaho

I have tried many time to connect Pentaho CE to database in SQL Server 2005 but not successful. I first did this from Ubuntu on which Pentaho CE installed. It seems impossible to connect to SQL Server. I then installed Pentaho CE on the same machine with SQL Server and was following [official guide](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Manually+Configuring+an+MS+SQL+Server+2000+and+2005+Connection) to set it, failed.

The steps are:

- Download MS JDBC driver (version 4) and place it in `pentaho\bi-server\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\WEB-INF\lib` and `pentaho\administration-console\jdbc` respectively
- after that, I go to Pentaho console to create a new data source and set everything as the manual said.

However, it always prompts that "No suitable driver for ..."

Does anybody meet this issue or could give a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I solved it. It's not so mystery, and don't need to modify any files. There are two important things:

First, use jtds driver instead of MS JDBC drivers, although MS JDBC 4 is working (but not so good, the earlier version not working with Java 6 and later at all). Place the driver in corresponding directories beneath administration-console and biserver-ce. You may notice that the directories in the new Pentaho version are different from before. They should look like:administration-console/jdbc/ and biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/lin/

Second, you have to provide the instance type in the URL. The correct URL looks like: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instance=MSSQLSERVER;DatabaseName=test. It's very tricky that MS SQL Server has different URL format for each version. You have to find the right one.

One more thing is that, (I think) you have to enable the SQL Server Authentication in MS SQL Server 2005 to connect with it.

Comment: I had to add the path to sql_auth.dll in the libs path in Spoon.bat to get it to use Integrated Security.