# Pentaho biserver using sql server DB installation

Tags: sql-server, pentaho, business-intelligence

I'm new in this field, please kindly help me.
I'm installing pentaho biserver for community in my notebook. At first, it's succeed (with default configuration) [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGXCD.png). but, when I'm trying to change the database with ms sql server like this tutorial,

[help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.4/0F0/0K0/040/0D0](http://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.4/0F0/0K0/040/0D0)

an error occurs:
[image: an error occurs]

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with the installation?

I'm using:

- Sql server developer edition 2014
- pentaho biserver community 4.8.0
- apache-tomcat-8.5.3
- jdk8
- sql server driver sqljdbc42.jar and I put it under `\biserver-ce\tomcat\lib`

I also try something like [Using Pentaho Community Edition with SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192158/using-pentaho-community-edition-with-sql-server-2005) but still not working.

Comment: At this point you should take a look into the log files of the Pentaho BI server installation. It seems that it depends on Tomcat, so these files could be in `tomcat-dir\logs` or in `tomcat-dir\webapps\[pentaho-folder]\WEB-INF\logs`. You should find a more specific error and can edit your question then.

Comment: switch to default configuration.
no need to do anything. while creating Datasource connection Pentaho provides option for different RDBMS connection.
You just need to place JDBC connector file into lib directory.

Comment: @tobi6 ok. I'll try again and edit the question later.

Comment: @WorkingHard.. so there is no need to edit anything from the defaulf configuration? just copy the jdbc to tomcat\lib?

Comment: yes. correct.
just select sql server database and provide authentication details while connecting.

Comment: @WorkingHard.. please move your comment to answer, and i will accept it

Comment: @Tari done.. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch to default configuration. **no need to do anything**. while creating Datasource connection Pentaho provides option for connecting to different RDBMS database.You just need to place JDBC connector file into lib directory.